# How do I use chrome driver to click a button in a frame in a pop up window, then get back to my original window?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I would, naively it seems, expect this code to click a button that opens a popup, switch to the popup, find the results frame (thanks sales force!) click a button there then finaly switch focus back to the original page.

Instead I get a 500 server error on the final switch to 'home'.

What should I be doing? I am using  ChromeDriver 19.0.1068.0

Thanks

```
PageHelper.CountryButton.Click();
var home = _driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

           foreach (var window          in _driver.WindowHandles)
            {
                if (_driver.SwitchTo().Window(window).Title.Contains("Search"))
                {
                    _driver.SwitchTo().Frame("resultsFrame");
                   PageHelper.Country.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }


           _driver.SwitchTo().Window(home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no solution to this but I expect it is related to this issue

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1167